# How to check string is English or German or any other language other than English using java

Tags: java, utf-8

I have to prepare a property file where key is English and value can be other than English, like German, Chinese, Korean, French. I read key and value from xml file. I used one linkedhashmap, as sequence also matters, now if:

1. first encounters key and value both are English, I inserted in map, next time if key is same but value can be in German, then I to replace English word with German.
2. if first time I found English key with German value, i hv to do nothing.

I tried to get bytcodes with UTF-8 but it works for korean or chines but not in German.

```
byte[] bytes = value.replace(" ", "").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

or

```
if(value.charAt(i)>=128){
    ret = false;
}
```

I need a method which accept string as input, if string is English return true, rest for all language it should return false.

```
boolean isEng(String abc){
if(abc is english)
return true;
}
else
return false
}
```

abc = "Change Password" should return true,
abc = "Changer le mot de passe" should return false

Answer (score 1):

I would *strongly* advise you to have separate property files, one for each language. Heck, that's the scenario that [`PropertyResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) is *made* for.

Fundamentally you can't tell what language a word is - there are many words which are valid in multiple languages, sometimes with the same meanings and sometimes with different meanings. (Think "formidable" in English and French for example...) Heck, a single word *in one language* can have multiple meanings...

Imagine you have keys K1 and K2, and values A and B, with the following mappings:

```
English K1 = A
German K1 = B

English K2 = B
German K1 = A
```

That may sound far fetched, and I'm not about to look for an example of it, but it's far from impossible.

Any time you want your code to make a decision based on whether it *thinks* a particular word is in one language or another, you're in a world of pain. For a larger piece of text, with enough work, you can determine this heuristically - but even so it'll never be perfect. For single words, it'll be a lot worse than "not perfect".

Comment: I'm already preparing separate property file for all languages, but problem is while preparing property file only. I don't know first encounter will give right translation or second.i.e for french: Change Password=Changer le mot de passe , Change Password=Change Password

Comment: @user3359947: My point is that if your language data is combined to start with, with no indication of which value is for which language, you're on a hiding to nothing. You're simply not going to get anything sensible from that.